# If atleast one result of vlookup is X, then do Y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a table like this (simplified):

Column A - IDs (not unique values, numbers)
Column B - Active or Inactive (as a text)

i would like to find a function, that would find all occurences of an ID and find, if any of the occurence has the Active value in column B. Something like this:

The ID has atleast one active in column B:

[image]

The ID has only inactive in column B:

[image]

I was trying to combine vlookup and countif, but to no success. Any idea?

I was trying to combine vlookup and countif

Comment: Try `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(A$2:A$11=E2)*(B$2:B$11="Active"),0)),"Active","Inactive")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `FILTER()` and then compare with ***Active***.

```
=IF(OR(FILTER(B2:B10,A2:A10=E2)="Active"),"Active","Inactive")
```

For older versions of Excel, you may try-

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$10="Active")*($A$2:$A$10=E2))=0,"Inactive","Active")
```

[image]

Comment: Great use of `OR`. It seems the first one could be achieved without the `FILTER` function: `=IF(OR((A$2:A$11=E2)*(B$2:B$11="Active")),"Active","Inactive")`.

Answer (score 1):

With a Sum function

```
=IF(SUM((E2=A$2:A$11)*(B$2:B$11="Active"))>0,"Active","Inactive")
```

Answer (score 1):

*i would like to find a function, that would find all occurences of an ID and find, if any of the occurence has the Active value in column B. Something like this*

Piece of cake. What you want is to count if there is an ID with at least 1 active status, so you just need a simple COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11;E2;$B$2:$B$11;"Active")>0
```

This formula will return TRUE if there is at least one `Active` value related to ID, else FALSE.

[image]